# Can you lock a single application variable in .Net?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, locking

In .Net web service you can set application level variables like this

```
application("Stackoverflow") = "Stack"
application("Serverfault") = "Server"
```

If you receive multiple requests, you can simply lock, then update, then unlock

```
try
  application.lock()
  application("Serverfault") = "Fault"
finally
  application.unlock()
end try
```

Now, this locks all the application variables, is there a way to just lock a single application variable? Instead of all the application variables at once?

Comment: You should be aware that the main raison d'être of the Application-level variables is backwards compatibility with legacy ASP applications.  For modern ASP.NET applications, there are better solutions, such as using static fields in a class protected by a lock (C#) or SyncLock (VB.NET) statement.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, I had a different issue I was researching, which I think provides me a solution the question I posted.

This:

```
  Using mutex = New Mutex(False, "LockServerFault")
      mutex.WaitOne()
      application("ServerFault") = "Fault"                                      
      mutex.ReleaseMutex()
  End Using
```

Accomplishes the same thing as:

```
try
  application.lock()
  application("Serverfault") = "Fault"
finally
  application.unlock()
end try
```

But it doesn't lock all application variables, but it does prevent the single application variable from being updated at the same time. This enables me to update different application variables in different threads, without making all threads pause for application variables that don't apply to them.

Comment: Nice and thanks. I found this while trying to figure out how to get a singleton MemoryCache working in ASP.NET Core, where Application.Lock doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation on [Application.Lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184(v=vs.90).aspx).

> The Lock method blocks other clients from modifying the variables stored in the Application object, ensuring that only one client at a time can alter or access the Application variables.

So looks like the answer is no. Not unless you provide your own custom locking strategy and forgo the use of `Application.Lock()` and even then I am not sure how the state is persisted in the `Application`, if the whole state is serialized on change then you could definitely not do it.